# How to scrape jmeter metrics by Prometheus running in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, prometheus, k3s, k3d

I'm running a test application and Jmeter on one cluster and Prometheus in a separate Kubernetes cluster, all created on the same bare metal. Through LB, I can access my application from company intranet as "host ip:8080" and access prometheus as "host ip:9090". My Jmeter is using the prometheus listener and runs in a pod. It is pushing the metrics to localhost:9270.

I have edited values.yaml (helm prometheus values)  to add jmeter job with target as localhost:9270 but the target always showing down. I'm not sure what/how prometheus from the other cluster can scrape the jmeter metrics from the other cluster. Looking for some guidance.

EDIT: Some more context:
In the remote server, I created prometheus cluster like this: sudo k3d cluster create prometheus -p "9090:80@loadbalancer" --k3s-arg "--no-deploy=traefik@server:*" and I can access it on my local with the server ip and port 9090. The other cluster in the same server where my application and jmeter run, I created the cluster like this sudo k3d cluster create myapp -p "8080:80@loadbalancer" --k3s-arg "--no-deploy=traefik@server:*". I can access my application with server port:8080.

Kubectl get pods -A: (Please see the job-executor-service pod in jes-keptn namespace. This pod creates a new pod in run time that executes jmeter and when test finishes that run time pod changes to Completed status. When that jmeter pod runs, I have logged into it and seen the Jmeter metrics at localhost:9270 inside the pod)

[image]

Kubectl get svc -nkeptn (from application/jmeter cluster)

[image]

This is my other cluster running promethus:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what `values.yaml` are we talking about? (helm? related to prometheus deployment?). I don't understand your setup from your description, but that, `localhost:9270` sounds wrong. prometheus would have to fetch metrics from a remote address, not its loopback

Comment: Yes this one: sudo helm get values prometheus > values.yaml. Just to add some more context here: In the remote server, I created prometheus cluster like this: sudo k3d cluster create prometheus -p "9090:80@loadbalancer" --k3s-arg "--no-deploy=traefik@server:*" and I can access it on my local with the server ip and port 9090.  The other cluster in the same server where my application and jmeter run, I created the cluster like this sudo k3d cluster create myapp -p "8080:80@loadbalancer" --k3s-arg "--no-deploy=traefik@server:*". I can access my application with server port:8080.